# How can I get current time in a +7 timezone on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to get the +7 timezone on iPhone, how can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: if you know the current tize zone (for example +4), [NSDate date] will return current date and time, add +3 (to make it +7) to it.

Comment: @Satyam svv: your comment is misleading. An `NSDate` object represents a certain absolute point in time. It is independent of time zones. By adding 3 hours to a given `NSDate` object, you are not moving between time zones. You are moving in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output the date, create an `NSDateFormatter` instance and set its time zone to the one you want. Then use the date formatter to create the date string.

If you want to get the date components (day, hour, etc.) of a date in a given time zone, create an `NSCalendar` instance, set its time zone accordingly, and send a `components:fromDate:` message to the calendar object.